# Connecting to AWS EC2 instance from Docker SDK for python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

I have created a free tier EC2 instance for deploying a docker image. I am planning to do it through a python program which uses the Docker SDK for Python. In the documentation of the package , the connection is made to the docker instance using the following code snippet

```
import 
client = docker.from_env()
```

How can I specify the details of my AWS EC2 instance here so that I can connect to it directly and do operations such as deploy a new image, list active containers etc.

If it is possible to specify the connection parameters such as my username, password, host address and server location here, how can I do it through creating secrets for these params in the app.

I tried connecting using the syntax mentioned but I couldnt find how to make the connection to a cloud instance.